# Difference between jquery.ui.theme.css and jquery.ui.css

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to do a project of dashboard on jquery ui. Using the themeroller, i am able to customise the theme. The downloaded folder contains two css jquery.ui.theme.css and jquery.ui.css. I am confused which file should i use? what is the purpose of each file.
I would be thankful for the help and clear suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes are designed to create a visual consistency across an application and allow components to be themeable by **jQuery UI ThemeRoller**. The class names are split between ui.core.css and ui.theme.css, depending on whether styles are fixed and structural, or themeable (colors, fonts, backgrounds, etc) respectively.

jQuery UI Document say that `jquery-ui.css` is just `jquery-ui.theme.css` appended to `jquery-ui.structure.css`. If you download these files from ThemeRoller both `jquery-ui.css` and `jquery-ui.theme.css` will contain custom changes. `jquery-ui.structure.css` remains the same across customizations.

**ThemeRoller CSS files**

1. **jquery.ui.css** is core CSS of jQuery UI
2. **jquery.ui.theme.css** is customized theme css which overwrites some attributes and styles of jquery.ui.css.
3. **jquery-ui.structure.css**  is responsible for the layout and functionality.

**Reason for not using jquery-ui.css**

It makes sense to offer a split version of these files in order to use something like cdnjs for jquery-ui.structure.css but your own server (or CDN solution) to deliver your customized jquery-ui.theme.css.

Or if you use multiple themes on your site it allows for smaller data traffic because the browser might already have a cached version of jquery-ui.structure.css when encountering an uncached theme (jquery-ui.theme.css).

**Customization besides Themeroller**

For our customization you can make custom.css file. and you can include that file after include css files provided by ThemeRoller. So We can override properties of class easily.

Comment: And  I would also like to know what is the use of jquery-ui.structure.css . This is also included  in the folder . Should i include this file also?

Comment: I would also like to know the proper way of customising the theme beside the themeroller option

Comment: I have updated my answer, first I have wrote some wrong information about include jquery.ui.css file. but it not mendatory to include.

Comment: Welcome, If you like this answer, please up vote it and mark as correct.

Comment: Didnot properly get the concept"jQuery UI Document say that jquery-ui.css is just jquery-ui.theme.css appended to jquery-ui.structure.css.". Could you explain more clearly. I am novice and it is my first project on jquey ui. And i cannot grab the properly what it meant by"The class names are split between ui.core.css and ui.theme.css, depending on whether styles are fixed and structural, or themeable (colors, fonts, backgrounds, etc) respectively." So you said not to use jquery-ui.structure.css, then which files should i include? Please eplain clearly. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: For more information in detail you have to read Doc https://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.11/#simplified-custom-and-quick-downloads